# Triggering Edit with RowDblClick on RadGrid = error on second item

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have this very strange behavior in the Telerik RadGrid ...
I'll paste snippets of what I have to try and make things clear.

```
<ClientSettings>
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" EnableDragToSelectRows="False"/>
    <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" />
</ClientSettings>
```

allows me to catch the doubleclick on the row.
The following should trigger the editmode properly ... and it does ... EXCEPT for the second row in the grid!!!

```
function RowDblClick(sender, eventArgs) {
    editedRow = eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical();
    $find("<%= radGridInvestering.Client %>").get_masterTableView().editItem(editedRow);
}
```

The following error occurs:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Selection out of range

if anyone has an idea, I'd be VERY happy to hear about it. I cannot be the first dev with this problem ... I think